# Getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 When I use different delimiters for splitting strings

Tags: java, regex

I'm getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 and have no idea how to fix it. It happened when I change my delimiter from (",") to ("^[A-Za-z]+). Here is the method I'm having the problem in:

```
public void populateArrayList() throws FileNotFoundException{
    File inputFile = new File("StirlingHistoric.csv");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(inputFile);

    while(scan.hasNext()){
        String line = scan.next();
        String [] input = line.split("^[A-Za-z]+"); // try get the useDelimiter method to work instead
        addEntry(input[0], input[1], input[2], input[3], input[4], input[5]);      
    }
    scan.close(); 
}
```

The program crashes at the call to addEntry. The thing is if I use the:

`String [] input = line.split(",");` as delimiter it works fine but there is still other symbols in the .csv file I have to get rid of, mostly just quotation marks, so it made sense to use the `("^[A-Za-z]+")` delimiter.

I have uploaded two images of my debugger that gives some information of whats happening in the array. I have highlighted (in the images) some lines of code in green and blue to draw attention to them. And have also made some comments on the images. Here is the links:

Pic 1: http://tinypic.com/r/25hdbgx/8

Pic 2: http://tinypic.com/r/35lb3nt/8

Just click on the image to enlarge it. If you would like me to post the entire class this method belongs to just let me know. Thanks

Comment: you may wanna evaluate the size of your array before trying to access its members `if ( input.length >=6 ) addEntry(...`

Comment: @mazaneicha I just put in the if statement there and it let me pass i.e I didn't get an out of bounds exception but it left out the REFERENCE and the first part of the ADDRESS for every entry in the file

Comment: you should check that your new regex actually produces the results that you expect. Try `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(inputs));` to see if the resulting tokens are per your expectations.

Comment: I'll give that a try now :)

Answer (score 2):

Put the `^` inside the `[]` to match a chararcter except.

```
"[^A-Za-z]+"
```

A `^` outside matches the beginning of the input.

Also, test the size of the resulting array:

```
if(input.length < 5 ) /* do something */;
```

Comment: hi, just tried that there but it doesn't seem to have fixed them problem

Comment: please, paste the results of `line.split("[^A-Za-z]+")`

Comment: The results of the line.split("[^A-Za-z]+") with the ^ inside meant the strings were going into the array properly now i.e index 0 [REFERENCE],  index 1 [ADDRESS],  index 2 [CATEGORY],  index 3  [DATE],  index 4 [COUNCIL],  index 5 [PARISH] and now says the array size is 6 which is correct now so the ^ inside worked however I still get the arrayindexoutofboundsexception: 2

Comment: Also, test the size of the resulting array: `if(input.length < 5 ) /* do something */;`

Comment: I just tried the if statement  mazaneicha suggested above and it let me pass however most of the results were missing. I'll try the if statement you suggested :)

Answer (score 0):

edit:

How do you know when the code hits `addEntry` if there even is a `input[5]`? Or is that a constant factor in the file? You know for sure that when you split the input string there will only be arrays of 6 elements and not smaller? Because if thats the case then it explains the arrayindexoutofbounds exception on that line.

A solution to that would be to pass the input array as a parameter in the addEntry method and deal with different lengths there.

Comment: Do you know of a service that would let me post the file so you could see it for yourself? I feel like you are on to something because although each line of the file has a  Reference, Address, Category, Date, Council and Parish for some reason the program doesn't always pull every piece of this data from every line. Sometimes the parish an council are missing from some of the entries. I thought it might be something to do with the way the csv file was formatted but it looks all the same to me

Comment: Thats perfect here's the link: http://www.filedropper.com/stirlinghistoric it is a csv file so maybe you might want to change it to a .txt file so you can see the quotations and commas in it :)

Comment: I can upload it as a text document if that would be better. When I open that csv file on my mac it opens in excel so I can't see the commas and quotation marks around the text but as a text file I can

Comment: I think the file explains it. if Line 2=  51326,"STIRLING UNIVERSITY CAMPUS, BRIDGE OVER AIRTHREY LOCH",C,15/05/2009,STIRLING,LOGIE and it splits into [0] Stirling university campus, [1] bridge over airthrey loch, [2] stirling, [3]logie and not more, your program has a problem because [4] doesnt exist but the addentry needs it as parameter. As i suggested in my answer, pass the array as parameter and not it's elements.

Comment: I'm sure line 2 still splits into 6 elements? [0] 51326,   [1] STIRLING UNIVERSITY CAMPUS, BRIDGE OVER AIRTHREY LOCH,   [2] C,    [3]15/05/2009,  [4] STIRLING, [5] LOGIE. No?

Comment: Not with that regex you are using, it only matches characters

Comment: Okay so I should change [^A-Za-z]+ regex to something else then :)?

Comment: I would pass the the input[] as a parameter except my addEntry method already takes 6 parameters that get passed in when a user wants to add more entries from the GUI so for me to pass the string [] input at a parameter I believe I would have to edit quite a bit of my code?

Comment: Looking at the file, i think you could just use `input.split(",");` Looking for a solution to overcome `"`

Comment: Well, if you used the array as a parameter, the method would look like `addentry(input);` and at the addentry method it would look like `public void addEntry(String[] input){//do something}`. You havent posted whats going on in this method, but working with the array or the elements, i don't see much code that needs to be changed.

Comment: Yeah thats what I was originally using however as you know, I still had to get rid of the quotes around the strings :). Would you like me to post the other classes and let you run the program

Comment: For the `"` you can use the regex of `"[\p{"}]"` i think, not sure im not a regex expert (yet). As response to your last comment. I think it's best that you tried first with the solutions offered in this topic. If you run into another problem then just create a new question for that.